# have to put page number on "footer-image-logo" while printing webpage

Tags: html, css

i have set footer-image in print page by using this code.

```
@media print {
    div.divFooter {
        position: fixed;
        background: url(http://path/to/image.png);
        height: 100px; /* put the image height here */
        width: 100px; /* put the image width here */
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

i have to put dynamic page no. like 1/5 , 2/5 , 3/5..etc where 5 is total no of page..how can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@page {
  @bottom-left {
    content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you alex. this is css property but is it require to put class in html file? like.. <div class="bottom-left"> </div>

Comment: @Denish you don't need to add any HTML.

Comment: @alex. i am not getting reflection in my "print-prview" after putting this code in my css file..

Comment: @Alin Yep, otherwise I'm not sure how you would reliably compute the page number.

Comment: @alex Sorry, it may be me, but I don't understand what you're trying to do with those `counter`s. Where do you set the values of `page` and `pages`?

Comment: @Alin You don't. [Check this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#pg-based-extensions).

Comment: @alex Got it. I didn't pay enough attention to the question... +1

Comment: Not sure why this got accepted. Paged media margin boxes are not yet implemented in ANY major browsers. As of today this code has exactly no effect.